# Why AWS ALB not provide to use static IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, load-balancing

I have question about ALB.

I heard that need to use NLB, if I want to use static Ip for Loadbalancer.

Because ALB not support static IP service.

So I want to know why ALB not support that

I found another stackoverflow answer.

[In AWS, why is that an NLB can provide static IP addresses whereas an ALB cannot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934851/in-aws-why-is-that-an-nlb-can-provide-static-ip-addresses-whereas-an-alb-cannot)

But I want to know more detail that why it is better not to use a static IP in the application layer.

I'm not good well English. If you don't understand my question. let me know. I will edit to my posting

thank you

Comment: How did it go? Still confused about static IP and ALB?

Comment: Oh sorry for reply late. thank you sir! I got it what you are mean  your mean is AWS some kind business strategy. Is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because ALB not support static IP service.

By default it does not, but you can  add [Global Accelerator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/latest/dg/about-accelerators.alb-accelerator.html) to ALB and get static IPs for it. From [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/improving-availability-and-performance-for-application-load-balancers-using-one-click-integration-with-aws-global-accelerator/):

> Once enabled, you are able to see the new accelerated endpoint’s details, such as the **two static IP addresses** and the global DNS name, right in the ALB console. Let’s take a look at how to use this feature.